# How to read data from a table in PDF, but the PDF also contains images?

Tags: c#, pdf

I have searched for a solution, but the examples that I have found are only for PDF's where there are no images inside the PDF file but only tables.

My question is how is it possible to read the table at the bottom right corner of a drawing(see picture) and get that data back as a table or string? I saw some people using iTextSharp, but this convert all text to a string and not the table text. I only want the tables from the PDF file/drawings being read and return as data (string or datatable).

I also used SpirePDF, but it can't read PDF files with images in it.

I tested Spire with a PDF where only tables were in and then it works.

EDIT: The table is always on the bottom right corner, but can be different in size.

Regards,

Giorgio

[PDF File 1 with table on the bottom right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ino9H.png)

[PDF File 2 with table on the bottom right, but a bigger table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FP6SW.png)

PDF files download from Drive:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/18d9uMxBxuLQE2onrTcz2ZvM2TrkhOQHt/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NMNnFM2CFVv-4t9Sn6jh53dDkgkhmtI7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please send us a copy of the pdfs rather than image files. Thanks.

Comment: @jose_bacoy Just uploaded the PDF files.

Comment: The pdf files are not accessible.

Comment: @NineBerry Just opened them. They are now accessible.

Comment: @KJ Thanks , so i need to figure out to get the locations of the tables in the file and try to extract only those text data. I will try to work on it see if i can get something.

Comment: The [PDFDocument.ParsePages](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/dh/pdf/pdfdocument-parsepages.html) method from the LEADTOOLS Document Toolkit can collect all text objects in the PDF document. Once parsed, you can analyze and process the result to obtain the desired text. For example, you can locate the table header, "Algemene gegevens (Tenzij anders vermeld)", and use the parsed bounds information to isolate the target text from the collected result. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor)

Comment: I have used the SpirePDF package in combination with GIMP to get the exact coordinates of the place that I want to extract as text. This works perfect. Thanks everyone for the help and information.